# Net Force On An Object

Tags: kinematics

If 5 different forces are acting on an object in the same direction, is it possible for the net force to equal 0? Could Friction or Gravity make this possible? If so then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, easily. We don't have to invoke any specific force like friction or gravity--just imagine a block at rest on the ground, and forces act either to the right or to the left. I could have four forces each of $F = 1N$ on the right, and one force on the left of $F = 4N$, and that would balance. The question is akin to asking "can we add up five different numbers and get zero?"

Edit: I've just seen that you said "in the same direction"in which case the answer is no, unless they are all zero. You mention friction, but if static friction is to be included in the equation it will act in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

If a object weighs 6 lbs and there are 5 1 lb forces pushing up, then it will not move. The ground pushes up, causing a zero net force.

Comment: Net Force is the total force acting on an object though right? So does it only count is the object moves?

Comment: @DragonSlayer3 net force on this object is zero. This is because the object is falling down, but the earth resists pushes up. In short, every object with a non-zero net force will accelerate.

Comment: In this example there is an additional force which you should mention, the normal force of the ground that provides the other 1lb to keep the object stationary. If an object actually only has +5 lb force up and -6 lb force down, then it will accelerate downward.

Comment: @HDE226868 no, then I wouldn't need the ground

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible,if the total of those five forces is equal to the force of friction or gravity.then it is possible .
eg. suppose if the sum of five forces in one same direction is 1N and the friction applied on that object is also 1N then the net force on that object will be zero. as they will cancel out ....

Comment: Well as zeldredge says, you don't really need to invoke friction, all you need is $\sum \mathbf F=0$.